# Charitable Contributions and the Income Tax

Tags: united-states, income-tax

It is my understanding that for somebody who does not itemize, you can deduct a small amount of charitable contributions on your income tax in tax years 2020 and 2021. However, you cannot take any deduction for charitable contributions in 2022 if you do not itemize.

Am I right about this?

Comment: I’ve not heard of that. Where did you get that information?

Comment: @RonJohn You can look here for more information: https://www.aarp.org/money/taxes/info-2021/how-to-deduct-charitable-donations.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right. In 2020 and 2021 there was a $300 ($600 for MFJ) deduction allowed above the line for charitable contributions, as part of the [CARES act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CARES_Act), initially for 2020 only, but extended to 2021 as well. [This provision was not extended to 2022](https://giving.stanford.edu/stories/cares-act-not-extended-for-2022/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that ability to claim $ 300 on the main form 1040 itself (line was right under the standard deduction line) was eliminated for 2022.

And the overall changes to itemized deductions and the standard deduction were enacted in the Tax Cuts and Jobs Act of 2017, which is [set to expire in 2025](https://www.taxpolicycenter.org/briefing-book/how-did-tcja-change-standard-deduction-and-itemized-deductions).

Comment: Good info, but should be a comment rather than an Answer since it doesn't directly address the question.

Comment: @keshlam I think it does address the question about not being able to do it in 2022

Comment: I edited it since keshlam's useful comment.